# Cannot install conda with pip and python 3.8

Tags: python, pip, conda, pypi

I can't install conda from my new python3.8 environment.

When I do

```bash
sudo python3.8 -m pip install conda
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement conda (from versions: 3.0.6, 3.5.0, 3.7.0, 3.17.0, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.7, 4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.1.2, 4.1.6, 4.2.6, 4.2.7, 4.3.13, 4.3.16)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for conda
```

I see that [conda](https://pypi.org/project/conda/) has been yanked from pypi but I have some other librairies that have dependencies with conda.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you read the whole PyPI page? *"It is the package manager used by [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/index.html) installations ... Currently supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda installer. You can download the miniconda installer from [https://conda.io/miniconda.html](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)."*

Comment: BTW, [you probably don't want to use `sudo pip`](/q/21055859/4518341).

Comment: You can try providing a specific version: https://pypi.org/help/#yanked

Comment: @topsail I wouldn't do that. It seems to be sorely out of date (version 4.3.16, released Apr 22, 2017 vs [latest version](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda) 23.5.0, released yesterday).

Comment: @wjandrea I understand, the thing is that I am in an ipykernel env, it has conda installed, it uses python3.8 to run kernels (in my jupyter) and when I want to install other libraries that has conda as dependecies, it fails like so : 
Collecting cmdstanpy
  Using cached cmdstanpy-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement conda (from versions: 3.0.6, 3.5.0, 3.7.0, 3.17.0, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.7, 4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.1.2, 4.1.6, 4.2.6, 4.2.7, 4.3.13, 4.3.16)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for conda

Comment: @Stevens Oh! If it's already installed, there's no reason to try installing it again. It looks like you should use `conda install` to install `cmdstanpy`, since it's [in the Anaconda repo](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cmdstanpy). **Edit**: it has more detailed installation instructions in [its docs](https://cmdstanpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0/installation.html). BTW, beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76342609/#comment134622392_76342609), you said `conda` is already installed. So, there's no reason to try installing it again in the first place; this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Instead, you should probably use `conda install` for the libraries you need. You mentioned `cmdstanpy`, which is [in the Anaconda repo](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cmdstanpy) and suggests `conda` first in the [detailed installation instructions in its docs](https://cmdstanpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0/installation.html). That said, `cmdstanpy` doesn't seem to depend on `conda` from what I can tell, so the error is probably caused by another package. I'd need to see the exact command you ran in the first place and the full output to be able to tell for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Conda is not installable via pip, use the [source](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html) instead

Answer (score -1):

Install official distribution conda at the official site. `conda` is not a package.

Comment: It ***is*** a package, but it's been yanked. Apart from that, [JL already posted the same thing](/a/76342919/4518341).

Comment: `conda` is an *import package* which, among other things, provides an alternate *distribution package* manager. (See the https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#glossary for more information.)